# Wordpress custom page get request

Tags: php, wordpress

I generate a link like this:
http://www.mywebsite.com/prova?name=asd

Where prova is the link to a Wordpress page. Into the template file page.php I add the php code to do a get request, but when I try to open the page Wordpress says that the page does not exist. If I try to open http://www.mywebsite.com/prova Wordpress opens the page.

The `GET` request is done in this way:

```
<?php echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';?>
```

How can I do a correct GET request on a custom Wordpress page?

Answer (score 0):

The query variable *name* is reserved by Wordpress, and is used for redirection.

Use a different query variable identifier, such as *n* or *project_name*